# How do I run the LEGO Technic V6 engine using a Lego electric motor?

Tags: motor, battery

I am not into LEGO, don't know anything about it, so I will try to be as specific as possible.

My goal is to spin the LEGO Technic V6 engine (preferably at some realistic RPM's like thousands).

Since I can't combust air and gasoline inside, my simple idea was to run it with LEGO electric motor from LEGO Technic Power Functions Motor Set 8293.

Obviously, I need to connect them somehow and make them run. I don't have any other LEGO pieces available. What do I need to buy (the minimum) to get this running?

Here's the type of V6 that I'm referring to:

[image: v6]

Hope that explains what I want and I hope someone can help me, I will be very thankful!

Comment: Welcome to Bricks! Could you clarify what you mean by a Lego Technic V6 engine? Are you thinking of something like this: https://images.brickset.com/sets/AdditionalImages/42083-1/42083_alt6.jpg (That's the V8 from the Chiron).

Comment: @jncraton Hi and thank you! I mean something like that, yes, but instead of buying the whole Chiron (expensive), I would buy this tiny.cc/wyfz7y (ebay).

Comment: I strongly doubt a plastic piston-shaker like this (i.e. the "v6 engine") can be run at thousands of rpm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your motor already has a Technic axle available, you'll need:

- Any Technic motor. You probably want an M motor ([8883](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/product/LEGO-Power-Functions-M-Motor-8883)).
- An appropriate battery box or other power source. If you selected the above motor, you probably want the PF battery box that uses AA batteries ([8881](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/product/LEGO-Power-Functions-Battery-Box-8881)).
- Any Technic elements that you want to actually mount the motor onto the V6. In the case of the above, you could get away with a shorter axle and a few Technic pins. If I were you, I'd either purchase a small Technic set (e.g. https://brickset.com/sets/42088-1/Cherry-Picker), or an assortment of Technic elements on Bricklink.

Most Technic motors aren't especially fast (~400 RPM). If you want an RPM up in the thousands, you'll need at least a couple of gears as well.

Comment: "I'd either purchase a small Technic set". Could you point me to a link for such a set so I can see what you mean by this?

Comment: Sure. Here's one example: https://brickset.com/sets/42088-1/Cherry-Picker If you have a specific design in mind, you can also purchase just the exact elements you need on Bricklink.